# SQL search on three fields from one parameter

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server Person Table:

- PersonId
- FirstName
- SecondName
- LastName

In my application I have one `TextField` where the user can input the Person Full Name. On `ValueChange` Event of my TextField on a background thread I call my `Stored Procedure` in order to get the search results.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_person_search]
@fullname nvarchar(100)
AS
BEGIN

SELECT
PersonId,
FirstName,
SecondName,
LastName
FROM Person
WHERE ....
// here I have to figure out how to search a person based on just one field

END
```

Any clue?

Comment: Can you modify the stored procedure?

Comment: I don't get what the problem is. You can simply do `WHERE PersonId = @fullname OR FirstName = @fullname (etc.)`?

Comment: I think that he has the fullname as a composition of the values in FirstName, SecondName and LastName where none of them is equal to the fullname but a concatenation of them is equal to the fullname. But what if there is no SecondName?

Comment: Yes I can modify the SP.

Comment: You already have an accepted answer, but you can turn on full text search in SQL Server and use either FREETEXT or CONTAINS on a composite key.  The other thing to do would be to change the application to have the individual fields.  I'm not sure if your doing homework, or if this is a production application, but it would be unusual to have a single name field in your application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not very elegant and probably not very efficient. Let's see if someone has a better idea.

Supposing that your @fullname is equal to "Mary Jo May"

```
SELECT
   PersonId,
   FirstName,
   SecondName,
   LastName
FROM Person
WHERE FirstName + ' ' + SecondName + ' ' + LastName = @fullname
```

There is also the problem of the missing SecondName possibility. In that case the concatenation of the fields could be wrong because you get two spaces concatenated without the SecondName

Answer (score 1):

Parsing user-entered data is one of the worst situations you can come across. Quick, write the code that will catch the problem with `'John Sm ith'`!

Your best option is to have input fields for each part of the name, which matches the form or the data in your table. Normally, I highly recommend against placing the burden on the user for making things easier for your code. But in this case, entering First Name, Middle (Name or Initial), Last Name is the de facto standard for almost all UI. As you travel around the Internet and enter your name at this site or that site, how many of them has one single text field for the complete name? I can't think of any, though I haven't been keeping track.

Even doing that, searching on names is troublesome. One method I find beneficial is to add a duplicate field for `Last_Name` called something like `Last_Name_Searchable`. It contains the contents of `Last_Name` but with all non-alphabetic characters removed and the remainder converted to all upper or lower case. So `Van der Snord-Griggel` becomes `VANDERSNORDGRIGGEL`. Then we can find the name even if a lazy user entered `van der snordgriggle` or any other variation (as long as it's spelled correctly).

A variation is to normalize a list of variations in a separate table. In my example above, there could be entries for `VANDERSNORDGRIGGEL`, `DERSNORDGRIGGEL`, `VANSNORDGRIGGEL`, `SNORDGRIGGEL`, `VANDERSNORD` and so on. I've never actually implemented this technique as it would need a lot of effort to maintain its usefulness. But for batch systems where you can't just flash a `Name not found` error and have the user try again, it might be useful.